# What's the most efficient way to do collision checking for a obb in grid map?

Tags: collision-detection

I have a dynamically changing grid map. There are many obstacles and they are dynamically changing at low frequency.
Now I have a obb (orinted bounding box), what's the most efficient way to do collision checking?
The situation is shown in the following figure, where red tiles are the obstacles and the green box is the obb which collide with one obstacle.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about the most efficient algorithm for this problem, but you could try to use Bresenham's line algorithm along the four sides of the OBB to find if they're colliding with a tile.

Of course this doesn't cover the case when a tile is inside the OBB and it's not touching any edges.